# calling java-script function after the post back to start a flash game

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

in my asp.net project i'd like to add a flash game, im using

```
<object width = "700" height = "500">
    <param id = "game_param" value = "<swf_src>" name ="movie"/>
    <embed id = "game_embed" src = "<swf_src>" width="700" height= "500">
    </embed>
</object>
```

to add the game to the page, and im using this jquery function to replace the attrabutes

```
function startGame(path) {
    $("#game_param").attr("value", path)
    $("#game_embed").attr("src", path)
}
```

my problem is, when i call this function with postback, the attrabutes are being reseted to thier orginal value, however when im calling it without postback while the attrabutes values are what i wanted the game isn't working. i tested and when i just entered the swf src to the source code it worked.

this is the button im using to call the jquery function:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="startGame("<real src>"); return false;" Text="Button" />
```

is there a way to do what im tring to do without creating a webpage for every game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render anything on page after the post back, and in your case you can render the function call, here is how (base on your code):

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

<script>
    function startGame(path) {
        $("#game_param").attr("value", path)
        $("#game_embed").attr("src", path)
    }
</script>
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="txtJsOnMe" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Literal>
```

and on code behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtJsOnMe.Text = "<script>startGame(\"<real src>\");</script>";
}
```

so after the post back will render the call right after the function, and you run your game.

Comment: @Plargato what error did you get ? what is render on page ? Yes its work, just look it out and check your bugs

Comment: i didn't get any errors, it just post backs and stays with the place holders in the value and src attrabutes

Comment: sorry i forgot to import jquery to the page i checked this on...
this does work